# Python Class Method Error -- unbound requires instance

Tags: python, class, static-methods

I'm calling

```
Hardware.gpio_active(True)
```

This is my Hardware class:

```
import os
import glob
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

#class to manage hardware -- sensors, pumps, etc
class Hardware(object):
    #global vars for sensor 
    base_dir = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/'
    device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + '28*')[0]
    device_file = device_folder + '/w1_slave'

    #global var for program
    temp_unit = 'F' #temperature unit, choose C for Celcius or F for F for Farenheit
    gpio_pin = 17 

    #function to enable GPIO
    @classmethod
    def gpio_active(active):
        #system params for sensor
        if active is True:
            os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
            os.system('modprobe w1-therm')
            GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
            GPIO.setup(Hardware.gpio_pin, GPIO.OUT)
            print 'activating GPIO'
        else:
            print 'deactivating GPIO'
            GPIO.cleanup()
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: unbound method gpio_active() must be called with Hardware
>   instance as first argument (got bool instance instead)

I don't want to pass an instance -- I want `gpio_active()` to basically act as a function but retain accessibility to static class variables.  I thought this is what `@classmethod` was for.  I get the same error with `@staticmethod`.

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: No, with `staticmethod` you should *not* be getting the same error. That's the description of [staticmethod](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#staticmethod) it does not implicitly pass an argument to a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `def gpio_active(active)` to `def gpio_active(cls, active)`.

Read more about `@classmethod` here: https://julien.danjou.info/blog/2013/guide-python-static-class-abstract-methods

Comment: Tried this earlier, same issue.

Comment: If you still get `TypeError ... got bool instance instead`, I guess that you may forget to save your code before run it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `staticmethod`:

```
@staticmethod
def gpio_active(active):
    ...
```

But it looks like you should be using a `classmethod` so you have access to other static/class methods for that class, or access to the class-level variables:

```
@classmethod
def gpio_active(cls, active):
    ...
```

Then replace `Hardware.gpio_pin` with `cls.gpio_pin`

Comment: I need access to other class methods & variables.
Either way I try I get the same error : - /

Comment: You can't be getting that error if you're doing the above. Are you sure your stacktrace isn't different in each case?